# Linear algebra problem involving concatenation of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix problem I don't know how to solve because I can't seem to express it as a multiplication of matrices.

Suppose I have the following 4x4 matrix $A$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\cr 0&0&1&1\cr 1&0&0&1\cr 0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

The problem is to find a 2x4 matrix $B$ such that the 4x4 matrix $C = \begin{bmatrix}B \cr BA\end{bmatrix}$ has full rank.

For example:

- $B_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\cr 0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is a solution, because $\begin{bmatrix}B \cr BA\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\cr 0&0&1&0\cr 0&1&0&0\cr 1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ has full rank
- $B_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\cr 0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is not a solution, because $\begin{bmatrix}B \cr BA\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\cr 0&1&0&0\cr 0&1&0&0\cr 0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ has rank 3

Is there a way to express this problem more naturally, so it has a solution using conventional techniques of linear algebra, rather than trial and error?

---

p.s. **note:** this is only an example, which is easy to do by hand; I'm wondering if there are any general methods for problems of this type, where the matrices in question might be much larger. I was hoping to be able to transform this equation into some kind of decomposition or nullspace problem.

For example, if it helped to calculate $D = \begin{bmatrix}B & BA\end{bmatrix}$ then this can be written as $D = BA'$ where $A' = \begin{bmatrix}I & A\end{bmatrix}$ and maybe I could use the structure of $A'$ to determine $B$ more directly.

(I'm interested in solutions with scalar calculation in $GF(2)$ but the math works out the same for these examples whether it's in $GF(2)$ or in "regular" algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be composed of the row vectors $(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$ and $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$.

Then the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}B\\BA\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 \\ b_3 & b_4 & b_1+b_2 & b_2+b_3 \\ c_3 & c_4 & c_1+c_2 & c_2+c_3\end{pmatrix}$ has full rank if and only if its determinant (which gives you a constraint for the variables) is nonzero.

Comment: I know that, but taking this approach requires you to construct the $\begin{bmatrix}B\cr BA\end{bmatrix}$ matrix and account for all these individual scalars by hand, so it doesn't lend itself to general matrix methods. (in addition, the calculation of the determinant is more expensive to compute than necessary to determine whether a matrix has full rank.)

Comment: @JasonS I understand after your edit that your matrix $A$ is not fixed, and that you don't want to find all $B$ satisfying the condition, but to get just one solution. Then as you say the determinant does not help you much...

Comment: ok thanks, i should have been more clear in my original problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the [observability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability#Definition), which if it is full rank also satisfies the [Hautus lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma). This states that the observability matrix would be full rank iff

$$
\text{rank}\begin{bmatrix}A^\top - \lambda\,I & B^\top\end{bmatrix} = n\quad \forall\ \lambda\in\mathbb{C}
$$

where $A$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix. The first term only loses rank when $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. In those cases the whole matrix still has full rank if the null space of $B^\top$ does not coincide with the null space of $A^\top - \lambda\,I$. In order words in your case the span of the of $B^\top$ combined with any $n/2$ eigenvectors of $A^\top$ should always contain $n/2$ linearly independent vectors (assuming that the eigenvalues of $A$ do not have a geometric multiplicity greater then one).

For example setting each column of $B^\top$ equal to the sum of two of the eigenvectors, such that each eigenvectors is only used for one of the columns of $B^\top$.

Comment: thanks... I've got to process your answer a bit to understand it some more. (I'm familiar with eigenvectors and eigenvalues but not sure how to calculate them in $GF(2)$.)

Comment: I am not familiar with $GF(2)$.

Comment: oh, it's just the Galois field where the elements are 0 and 1 and you add and multiply $\bmod 2$.

Comment: @JasonS Well, eigenvalues are roots of characteristic polynomials, so you need to work in an algebraic closure of $GF(2)$, in the same way you would work in $\mathbb{C}$ when doing linear algebra over $\mathbb{R}$.